# Pan foods and muscle gain

Tags: muscle-gain

I have heard as an example that if you eat at night Pan Potatoes increase the body fat. Can this help me add some kg if I eat every night?( its unhealthy way?)
What about eggs and bread on Pans?I like workout the morning I don't eat everyday eggs(I think I will have issues even I am 24) so if I eat eggs with bread that have been mixed on Pan could I destroy Protein and cardio?With other word this meal isn't helping me to increase the muscle size?
Generally Pans foods aren't good for muscle growth,doesn't affect our body to get big or those foods are unhealthy but  help grow our muscle ?Should be avoiding or should it be in our food source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear and define what is a diet. There is no magic food that will increase your weight or decrease your body fat. A balanced, adjusted to your needs and your goals diet will bring you the results you want.

If you want to gain weight (muscles) you have to make a calorie surplus diet. If you want to lose body fat you have to make a minus calorie diet.

If you just over eating you will just gain weight (muscles) + fat. On the opposite if you just under eating or not eating you will just lose fat + weight (muscles).

---

Let me make it clear for you.

**First** you have to calculate your daily calorie intake, there are several calorie calculators just try 2-3 of them and take the average, it will be about 90% correct but it doesn't matter for a beginner.

After you find your daily calorie intake, let's say ~2500cals, then you **adjust the surplus on your needs**. If you want to gain about 1kg per month you should go to ~2750cals, if you want to gain about 2kgs per month then you should go to ~3000cals. But that's enough, **don't go higher than that**.

Then you have to **calculate your macros**. So, again, find some macros calculators and decide what your daily Carb/Protein/Fat intake will be. At a ratio for each 50/30/20, which is a moderate ratio, suitable for a beginner and not only.

Finally you **choose the number of meals you want to eat per day**, 5-6 will be great. Breakfast, Morning-Snack, Lunch, Afternoon-Snack, Dineer, Before-Bed is a regular daily meal plan.

For example for all of these, for ~2750cals per day and 5 meals, the macros for 50/30/20 ratio will be 344 Carbs / 206 Protein / 61 Fat or per meal 69 Carbs / 41 Protein / 12 Fat.

Now you are done with the skeleton of your diet plan, you **can adjust the foods**. This is just an [excellent tool](https://www.myfitnesspal.com/) that will help you do that.

In general here is a sample weight gain plan:

> - **Breakfast**
>
> ***Egg Whites & ~1 Whole Egg*** (Yes you can eat eggs every day, cholesterol is on the yolk and will harm you if you eat more than 3
>   yolks every week. Eating 1 yolk will just benefit your body with
>   excellent source of good fats)
>
> ***Oatmeal***
>
> - **Morning-Snack**
>
> You can adjust it on what you prefer. ***Tuna, Turkey, Chicken
>   Sandwich with whole wheat bread***. Or ***greek yogurt, cottage cheese
>   and a fruit***. Plenty of choices
>
> - **Lunch**
>
> ***Chicken & Rice or Potatoes***
>   ***Salad***
>   ***Olive Oil***
>
> - **Afternoon Snack**
>
> Same as Morning Snack
>
> - **Dinner**
>
> Same as Lunch
>
> - **Before Bed**
>
> ***Greek Yogurt***
>   ***Almonds***

You can have red meat about 3 times per week, change the rice or the potatoes with pasta 3-4 times per week. You can have fish like salmod, tuna, tilapia 3 times per week. Beans or any other legume you like also 2-3 times. You can change the almonds with nuts or any other you like.

In general for all these, **don't fry your foods**, just prefer to eat your olive oil raw at your salad or your meal. Cooking at a stir fry, on grill or steam cooker are great choices.

**Adjust the amounts of those foods** (the grams of rice,chicken,etc) per meal for your needs and you will see the results you want.

Comment: Good answer, however, can you provide a citation for: "cholesterol is on the yolk and **will harm you if you eat more than 3 yolks every day**"

Comment: Your interpretation of those articles is a bit off, see this meta analysis: https://examine.com/nutrition/will-eating-eggs-increase-my-cholesterol/ https://examine.com/nutrition/are-eggs-healthy/

Comment: Actually it's about the same thing, the references on this meta analysis and the article from Harvard University are both from [PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed) . I don't think i have said something off or wrong but please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Just that it does not add much to your answer and is controversial at best. It would improve your answer to remove the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What i wrote is from in general case is been said for those things and it's not my opinion. In my opinion and personal experience, neither a yolk per day would make cholesterol go to higher levels, if your diet is balanced.